# Delete index from MySql - Same size of database

Tags: mysql

A mysql (5.5.59) MyIsam database has a sql filesize after mysqldump of 1,6 GB.
A table in the database had an fulltext index of 1,2 GB. 
I droped that fulltext index, because I dont need it anymore. The mysqldump filesize is still 1,6 GB.

I optimized that table already. How is it possible to give that size free?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqldump output only includes `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements. There is never any index payload in the dump file.

When you restore the dump to a new database, the indexes will be created as the table is filled by the `INSERT` statements. So there's no need to store indexes in the dump.

If you want your mysqldump output to be smaller, pipe it to `gzip`.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you so much. will give you the green arrow in 7 minutes.